# Removing a must-use plugin called Endurance Cache

Tags: wordpress, web

I have recently started creating my WordPress website and while working I realized that there were some issues - pages weren't saving properly and headers were disappearing. After a little research on the website, I ran into the "must-use" tab in the plugins section and found the Endurance Cache plugin.

The caching plugin was not functioning properly, and I wanted WP Fastest Cache as my go-to caching plugin. Thus, I went ahead and deleted the plugin from the FTP (wp-content folder).

Are there any negative implications to this? I reckon that since its a MUST-USE there must be underlying terms that prompt me to use it!

Any advice would appreciated! 
Thank you

Comment: Really weird that a plugin injected a file inside `wp-content/mu-plugins`. AFAIK, only the site admin should decide/manage what goes there or not. Looks like is a Bluehost issue: [Endurance-Page-Cache and PHP Edge Plugin](https://github.com/bluehost/endurance-page-cache/issues/34)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing necessarily different about removing a must use plugin over a traditionally installed plugin.

As to the specific plugin, Endurance Cache, it depends. If it stored data in the database for its caching functionality, that data could still be there. You would need to pursue [that plugin's support avenues](https://github.com/bluehost/endurance-page-cache/issues) to uncover what, if anything, should be done post-removal.

More on Must-Use Plugins: https://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins